# How i can hide my src file on inspect because it shows the whole file structure of my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, deployment, web-deployment-project

[image]

when I click on the inspect button and go to source option then it shows my whole folder structure how can I hide it ?. please help .

if any one of you knows the solution please help because its a very high priority issue from our client side

Comment: Sounds like you're shipping the sourcemap in your production build.

Comment: Your `source-map` is generated, look on the Internet to see how to turn it off. But is it generated in production as well?

Comment: Check if your website provides source-map as suggested above. Also, what helps to hide the structure and obfuscate function names and CSS class names is to use `webpack` that minifies and compiles everything into a bundle which is hard to decompose into separate files or modules.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if you are looking for this or not..
I personally tried two options

1. You can take a help of jQuery / Javascript, using which you can block or stop doing inspect in your app.
2. `"build:dev": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm run build",` by adding this flag when preparing build

Please set it for build command used for prod